# Continuity for maximal destablizing sheaves of nef sequences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth projective variety and $\mathcal{E}$ a torsion-free sheaf.

Let $\overline{\rm{NA}}(X)^{n-1}:=\{\sum D_1\cdots D_{n-1}\,|\, D_i \text{ is nef $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier}\}$ which is a subcone of $\rm{N}^{n-1}(X)$.

Let $\mathcal{E}_1^A$ be the maximal destablizing sheaf with respect to $A\in \overline{\rm{NA}}(X)^{n-1}$.

Denote by $\delta_A(\mathcal{E}_1^A):=c_1(\mathcal{E}_1^A)\cdot A\, / \text{ rank } \mathcal{E}_1^A$.

Then this defines a function $\delta: \overline{\rm{NA}}(X)^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ via $A\mapsto \delta_A(\mathcal{E}_1^A)$.

**Question**: is $\delta$ a continuous function on $\overline{\rm{NA}}(X)^{n-1}$?

In Miyaoka’s 87 paper “The Chern classes and Kodaira dimension of a minimal variety”, Corollary 2.4(3), it is known that $\delta$ is continuous on $\overline{\rm{NA}}(X)^{n-1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$.
Precisely, $\delta$ is continuous on any line segment between two rational points of $\overline{\rm{NA}}(X)^{n-1}$.
So I wonder what happens on the boundary of the cone.